# Combining multiple data from ID

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a question for my current [Spreadsheet A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfsvP.jpg).

Now I'm trying to make a new sheet for report generation where:

1. Report shows each ticket recorded on spreadsheet A.
2. Each ticket have 3 recorded process time. (Verification, Repair, QA)
3. The month for when the job ticket is first registered.

For illustration purpose, new sheet should look like this:

| Ticket ID | Verification | Repair | QA | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T-001 | X Hour | Y Hour | Z Hour | 9 |
| T-002 | X Hour | *Blank if no recorded time* | *Blank if no recorded time* | 9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Can Google Sheets do that? If can, how do I do it?
I have tried looking for some tutorial videos on Vlookup/Hlookup/Query/Search/Find, but I cant seem to get the results I needed.

EDITED: Changed question 3 from Name to Month

Comment: T-027 have two names.. how will the output be?

Comment: @p._phidot_, yes I've just realized that. I changed from Name to Month.

Comment: FYI, SO is not a service. Please read the following documentation, then edit, and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is not the most elegant but it works:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dEMYbI751pp55YF5M0V19U0QbytsabgwAO_97I1LXqw/copy

First get all ticket names using UNIQUE formula

```
=unique(C3:C)
```

When you got it, you have to find rows using 2 conditions:
Process & Ticket. In order to get it using VLOOKUP I make temporary array that contains Process and Ticket columns stitched together and duration column.
Then I use VLOOKUP using 2 stitched keys

=ifna(
arrayformula(
vlookup(G2&$F$3:$F,ArrayFormula({$B$3:$B&$C$3:$C,$D$3:$D}),2,false)))

[image]

Ifna prevents from error messages displayed when no value is found.
First arrayformula lets work this formula for an entire column.

Last task is to determine name of an employee. I use vlookup, but as name is futher left then Ticket, I have to make a temporary array {C3:C,A3:A} to search for name.

[image]

Warning: Vlookup is listing only first name found on the list.

Comment: Thank you for the respond and solutions. I have applied your solutions and it works really well. I have changed point 3 from Name to Month. How do I do the month? Thanks again!

Comment: After a few tweaks from your code, I managed to bring out the date instead of name. Thanks again!